# Windows 7's Windows Virtual PC - How to run VM in multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

Does the "Windows Virtual PC" that comes with Windows 7 Ultimate support multiple monitors?
I read online that VPC 2004 and 2007 added multi-monitor support but I did not find it in Windows VPC in Windows 7.

I am running Visual Studio 2010 in a VM and I would like to take advantage of the new multiple-monitor features of VS2010.

Edit: I would not like to use remote desktop - I am looking for an answer within VPC/VM only.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Win 7 box handy right now to test the VPC interface to see the right way to do this, but there is a quick work-around that works with all the virtualisation programs to get multi-monitor use.

Once you've started up your virtual machine, don't log into it, just minimize it. Now on your physical host PC run (by typing into the Start Menu search box, or into the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> run box) `mstsc /span`. When the box pops up type the name of your virtual machine, and log in when prompted. You should now be connected into your virtual machine and have it spanning across your monitors.

Comment: Thanks for the work around! I'd like to wait to see if somebody has an answer on how to do this from the VM itself...

Answer (score 1):

See also this article: [Use Dual Monitors in Remote Desktop Session on Windows 7](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/02/how-to-use-dual-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session-on-windows-7/)

which uses the new Windows 7 `use all monitors for the remote session` in the remote desktop client display option, rather than `/span`.

Comment: I don't want to use RDP if possible...

Comment: Then use VMWare Player. At the moment there is no other solution than RDP when using Virtual PC.

Comment: I just checked and confirmed: there is no way to do it in Virtual PC. Using VMWare would be the best solution if you want to avoid RDP.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but the free [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) has full multi monitor support.

You can use [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to convert the VPC machine to VMware.